# Which payment processor to use for the new 'Paypal checkout'?

Tags: contributions, paypal

A while ago there was a announcement that [CiviCRM now offers "PayPal Checkout".](https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/announcing-paypal-checkout)

Which payment processor should we be using to utilise Paypal checkout?

In the list of Paypal payment processors on the latest version of CiviCRM the options provided are:

- Paypal express
- Paypal Website payments pro
- Paypal Website payments standard

Ideally i'm looking for the simplest setup to remove PCI compliance responsibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [Omnipay extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/omnipay-multiprocessor-extension) to use Paypal checkout payment processor.

Comment: Yes, and if you read to the bottom of Eileen's post, you'll see this link that confirms this and gives you a bit of documentation: https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/blob/master/docs/Paypal.md

Comment: Awesome, missed that, thanks guys!

Comment: I have just seen that there may be some issues with membership renewal using a webform with Omni pay? Does anyone know if renewals / signups via webform will now work with omni pay?

Comment: Note that if you want to enable recurring payments, you'll need to have the feature "Reference Transactions" enabled on your PayPal account, as Eileen describes in her documentation. See discussion at https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/issues/132#issuecomment-562231663.